# azure front door - why do we need to add multiple backends to the backend pool

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

I'm a little confused about deployment architecture of Azure Front Door. for a backend pool, we can add multiple backends (typically from different regions),

such as:

myappbackendpool ->

- appbackend-eastus.appservice.com
- appbackend-westtus.appservice.com
- appbackend-europ.appservice.com

my question is, as the Front Door will eventually be deployed globally, why do we need those "backends" from different regions? Any reasons for that except for the healthy/backup considerations?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Front Door is just a caching and Load balancing solution. What if you have only one App Service and if it fails then then entire service will be down.

Also , another important aspect is, POP servers are located throughout the world and if you deployed your App Service in different regions, then POP servers will choose the endpoint which is closest to it.